# Rails unable to autoload constant only on first attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autoload

In my Rails 4 app, I have a base model, let's call it Badge, which lives in `/app/models/badge.rb`.

Then, I have a large number of specific badges that inherit from Badge, let's say `GoldBadge` and `SilverBadge` (and many more, in reality). All of these files live in `/app/model/badge/<name>_badge.rb`. For example, `/app/model/badge/gold_badge.rb`.

The class declaration for GoldBadge would look like this

```
class GoldBadge < Badge
  ...
```

However, the Rails (or Ruby, I don't really know) auto-loader, has trouble locating these files **only on the first attempt**. What I mean by that is when I first access a page that needs to use `GoldBadge`, for example, I get the following error:

```
Unable to autoload constant Badge::GoldBadge, expected /path_to_my_rails_app/app/models/badge/gold_badge.rb to define it
```

Which is weird, because the class is defined in that file. However, even stranger, is that if I then refresh the page, everything works - the class is found!

On a page where I reference multiple different types of these badges, I have to refresh the page once for each different type, before it will work. For example, if I had a page that used `GoldBadge`, `SilverBadge`, and `BronzeBadge`, I would refresh the page 3 times, with that error being shown once for each badge type, before it would finally work.

This happens in development mode. From what I've read, this might go away in production, but it's still very annoying in development mode. Any way to fix it (preferably without caching classes)?

Comment: I can duplicate your problem.....but it's not at all clear what you are trying to do.  Are you using STI?  Have you modified your config/application.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put it under namespace, like `app/models/badge` folder, you have do define your class like:

```
class Badge::GoldBadge < Badge
  #...
end
```

to autoload it and to be able to access it in the way like `Badge::GoldBadge`.
If you want to access it by just calling `GoldBadge`, then move it to `app/models` directory.

Comment: Thanks! I had previously namespaced the badges that way, but ran into problems because I wasn't referring to them as Badge::... in the rest of the code.

Comment: I have same problems. But I dont want to use namespace, but I want to store files with inherited classes in one folder. How I can do it?

Comment: @GenaShumilkin Which classes do you want to inherit? (I mean, is that model or library or something)

Comment: @GenaShumilkin Do you use Single Table inheritance, or models belong to different tables?

Comment: @GenaShumilkin And simple class definition like `class Cat < Animal ... end` doesn't work for you? BTW I am not sure I got your question clear, so you want all model files to go to `/models`, or you want to have STI classes under some `/models/animals` folder?

Comment: @FelixBorzik Yea, I want to store all my "animal" in `/models/animals` folder (IMO it's comfortable), but I have as same problems as author of this question: first try to load page - error, after refresh - all ok.

Comment: @GenaShumilkin It is not a Rails-way :) If you put something into folder, then namespace it and use classes like `Animal::Cat`. If you want to use STI and want to keep them in a `/models` directory, you can inherit it like `class Cat < Animal; end`, and it will work as well.

Comment: Neither this answer nor any of these comments actually answer the question. They provide an alternative solution, but they do not answer why it only fails to load the constants on the first attempt (e.g. why does it succeed on the 2nd attempt, at all times?).

Comment: @fgblomqvist The question asked to fix the error described. The answer provides a clear solution which actually worked for the person. They did not ask a question "why" this happened, so the answer you want to hear is outside of this answer's scope. You can post another question asking for an explanation, or research it using https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html as a starting point. My first thought is that Rails attempts to load a specific constant from said file, fails, but still loads constants from its contents, which are used during the next request.