# Rails: How to autoload constants successfully on first attempt without proper namespacing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

I want the following file structure:

```
app/components/foo/foo.rb
app/components/foo/_foo.html.haml
app/components/bar/bar.rb
app/components/bar/_bar.html.haml
```

Where I then can access the different classes like this:

```rb
Components::Foo
Components::Bar
```

Right now, for autoloading to work properly, it has to be structured/coded/accessed like this (hypothetically according to Rails convention):

```rb
Components::Foo::Foo
Components::Bar::Bar
```

That makes no sense. I want the previously mentioned file structure because I want my classes to be self-contained together with any resources/etc. belonging to them. I know that if the ruby file goes right inside `app/components` all will be well, but that means I have one folder and one file to keep track of, instead of just one folder. Not very nice.

Now, what's bothering me is that, just like the scenario presented here: [Rails unable to autoload constant only on first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992747/rails-unable-to-autoload-constant-only-on-first-attempt), the autoloading clearly works, but always only on the 2nd attempt. Since it is so systematic, it feels like it should be possible to configure things correct for it to work on the 1st attempt at all times.

This is the only addition I've made to the `application.rb`:

```
config.eager_load_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'components', '**/')]
```

I'm aware that a server restart is necessary in case new directories are added/existing directory structure is modified, but that's fine since that doesn't happen very often. Modifying the code obviously happens very often, and while I can keep refreshing the page multiple times until it has re-loaded all the constants, it is very frustrating (and tbh I haven't even tested it in production, but wouldn't be surprised if it does the same thing there on the first load).

I'm also aware that you might be able to work around this by using manual requires etc., and while I haven't had much luck with that anyway, it is still a much inferior solution since it would require a server restart if code is modified (assuming the requiring is done in a central place, such as in an initializer or in `application.rb`).

Comment: The way I leverage this (annoying) autoloading constraint is to have classes like `app/models/users/base.rb`, `app/models/users/admin.rb`, etc.

Comment: That still means that the classes would be defined in the same folder, right? I guess the short version of what I'm trying to achieve is to have classes in independent folders, without a namespace for each folder.

Comment: That's the problem with going against convention in rails. It often leads long sessions of hair pulling. But, I suppose some people like that sort of thing.

Comment: Abandoning Rails is high up on my list, partially for that reason.